# Disable all php warning in server log file wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have any issues my server log file reached 9 GB with in one month due to warnings of word press. I want to stop all the warnings generated by wordpress in server error log.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with WordPress, or PHP in general, is that by default, the error_reporting setting can be arbitrarily overriden at run-time. In WordPress you will find that many plugins, themes and even [WP Core](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/cff445d55f9bd53b608d3b9247ef62129aa9a816/wp-load.php#L24) set error_reporting themselves.

So even if you override it in your wp-config.php it won't do any good.

When using PHP < 8.0, if you want to keep your logs free of non-errors, the only way I have found is use a combination of these two directives in php.ini:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
disable_functions = error_reporting
```

To restrict to a certain path and disable all error reporting:

```
[PATH=/var/www/site]
error_reporting = 0
disable_functions = error_reporting
```

If you don't exclude E_WARNING, you will get warnings generated by the fact that the error_reporting function is disabled.

Note: `disable_functions` accepts a comma separate list of function names.

If you are using php-fpm you can set it like this:

```
php_admin_value[disable_functions] = error_reporting
```

When using PHP >= 8.0, disabling the `error_reporting` function generates a fatal error. WordPress Core has [partially fixed](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/50447) this but there are other places in the code, as well as in themes/plugins which still expect the `error_reporting` function to be enabled. This means the only safe way to disable this function when running WordPress is to also define a dummy function in `wp-config.php`, e.g.

```php
if ( !function_exists('error_reporting')) {
  function error_reporting() {}
}
```

Currently the `error_reporting` function is also used in `wp-admin/load-styles.php`, which does not include `wp-config.php`, so you'll have to add a patch or your own include for this file also.

If you don't have control over php.ini or the php-fpm config then you're out of luck, unfortunately.

Comment: This is the best answer I got to solve this specific issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it is just a page or two that is creating the issues (and assuming it is a PHP page) you could add a line to the top of the PHP page that are causing the issues

```
ini_set('error_reporting', 0);
```

but mevius is right, it is best to find and solve the errors instead of turning it off, otherwise there could be an error that you do need to pay attention to and will not know about ut

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of Wordpress will log database errors regardless of all settings, using the PHP command [error_log](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) .

The only way to disable this is to comment-out the command in the code.

Answer (score -1):

You can add the following to your .htaccess file to turn off error logging if you can't edit the php.ini file (if your webhosting supports this feature):

```
php_flag log_errors off
```

This will turn off error logging, it would be better to fix the issues that are causing the warnings ofcourse. But you could use this as a temporary solution to prevent huge log files while you try to fix the problem.